# Why are there holes in ice cubes in airplanes?

Tags: air-travel, factoids

It could be due to boredom that I notice this, but it seems that only on airplanes ice cube have holes. Why is that?

Comment: I have seen those in bars and restaurants too, I believe some machines are designed to produce these holes, apparently [they have some advantages](http://www.castelmac.eu/inglese/Icematic_cavi_fr.htm). Usually they are also cylindrical rather than cube-shaped.

Comment: I bet it's a choking thing. If I accidentally swallow a cube like the kind you are speaking off, I can still breath through the passage easier then a whole brick.

Comment: The reason is probably most trivial: greater surface area allows for a greater rate of cooling. Holes are a neat way to increase surface area without increasing overall dimensions of the ice cube.

Comment: This question would get more detailed answers on Physics SE, but I wouldn't go so far as to say it's off-topic here.

Comment: I doubt it is to prevent choking. There is a small angle across 2 axis of rotation that would allow you to breath thru an ice cube with a hole. The odds of it getting lodged at precisely that orientation is pretty small.

Comment: Airlines are a special case here compared to other outlets. Airlines need to maximise speed of service, and of clearing away. In fast food it is OK to provide loads of ice and less drink - while that may result in lots of unwanted and unmelted ice being left, they don't care. It is much slower and more difficult to clear away lots of tumblers which have ice left in them, than empty ones where the optimum amount of ice has been served and melted, so the latter is better on board aircraft. The greater area that promotes rapid cooling of the drink, by definition also warms and melts the ice.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Travel.SE, and does not state any actual problem to be solved](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Yet people didn't rain downvotes and VtC on it, as they do to [other comparable 'travel curiosity'-type questions](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4009/a-little-bit-confused-about-the-negative-perception-of-my-question). Please stop treating new users so badly and inconsistently, it reflects very badly on your community. If there is a scope issue here on Travel.SE, then fix it, already.

Comment: I have the same question about bricks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

They have the holes because of the machines that made them (check DavidG's answer), anyway this ice cubes with holes are better for planes for a few reasons:

- Because they are lighter (believe it or not, every gram in the aviation business counts, plus the ice is not made onboard, it is loaded prior to departure just like the food)
- They cool things faster due to larger area of contact with the liquid
- They also will allow more liquid to be filled in the already small airplane cups.
- Last thing, they do not tend to stick together in the ice bucket, so cabin crew won't need to smash it to break it down.

Comment: It also takes less energy to produce them (less volume/mass of water) for the same cooling power (surface area). On the other hand, it means you end up giving customers more beverage/less ice, which might have a cost in itself. ;-)

Comment: they can also be made clear because the freeze to the rod from the inside out so the ice has room to expand out rather than cracking when freezing from the outside in

Comment: @R.., On many flights, I receive the entire can (355mL?) It's not true of every airline, but it's common enough. So more beverage/less ice is not necessarily an issue.

Comment: Can you explain briefly why they do not stick together?

Comment: @Daniel that's a direct observation after years of flying as cabin crew.

Comment: This is incorrect - your answer merely lists side effects. DavidG has the correct answer.

Comment: The question was about airplanes, so I answered why these ice cubes good for airlines.

Comment: Anyway, I do not think my answer deserves this much of votes, its based on observation and experience, while other answer is more facts.

Comment: From the given points, we should be used holed ice cubes everywhere, rather than just airplanes.

Comment: Point 1 and point 3 seem to suggest that airlines should simply have used *smaller* ice cubes, rather than inventing the advanced new technology of *ice cubes with holes*.

Comment: I don't believe that the fact they are lighter is a factor. The ice cubes are made on demand from water already stored on the plane, making them using a different method doesn't change the overall weight. More liquid in the cups, also I don't think this is relevant as you could just make smaller cubes. And finally these types of cubes DO stick together, it depends on the ambient temperature, not the method of production.

Comment: DavidG is correct. The water is already on the plane. Whether it's in the form of an ice cube or not doesn't matter in regards to weight. Also, it's easy enough to make an ice cube with an equal mass to those in the shape of a cube (or any other shape.) The main reason for the hole is increased surface area which allows the cube to form much faster and also allows it to cool the drink (and melt) faster.

Comment: @reirab ice machine is not in the plane! ice is loaded in ground before take off..

Comment: @MeNoTalk That's interesting. Is that even true for the larger, long-haul aircraft?

Comment: If "every gram" mattered, they'd weigh the passengers before letting them board.  They'd have them empty scrap paper out of their pockets.  They'd always weigh carry-on luggage as well as checked luggage, and they'd weigh both in grams, not pounds or kilos.

Answer (score 35):

It's because the machine that creates the cubes has metal prongs that the ice 'grows' around.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The most efficient ice makers (and the majority of industrial ice makers) are not those that cool the surface, but those that use refrigerated metal prongs that stick down into the water pool. As the water freezes around the prongs, they rotate out of the pool and deposit the ice into a vessel.

Comment: +1 for detail. This is part of the point I was making without discussing the mechanics of the machine - the "surface" in this case is not the "outside" of the cube, but the inside. It comes down to the least distance between the cooling part (the "prong") and the outside of the cube. A thin wall will be more efficient to cool than a solid lump

Comment: But why do airlines use this machine whereas ice cubes we encounter in many other places seems not to be made with a similar machine?

Comment: @hippietrail Most likely because other places haven't bought a machine for making ice. Or perhaps there are others types that make other shapes and they are more expensive.

Comment: @DavidG: Which, in turn, lead to more questions: Why do airlines buy ice making machines that most other places serving ice do without? Why do airlines choose the less expensive of several available ice making machines which result in different shapes. In any case your answer makes it seem like a total coincidence in which the airlines definitely play no conscious decision making part whatsoever. Which is fine if it's true, but you don't show that it is actually true.

Comment: @hippietrail I suspect it's all based on cost. Ice machines make ice very quickly otherwise they would have to store pre-frozen cubes on board and keep them frozen (expensive freezers, more weight to carry.) Your local bar/restaurant can get away with making ice overnight if they already have the storage space.

Comment: I have to vote this down because it focusses arbitrarily on one point in a string of causes and effects and decides it is the "correct" one, with no justification, in a one-sentence answer.

Comment: This answer is correct.  My refrigerator has no ice maker, so recently I bought a standalone ice maker, and it makes ice the same way, with metal prongs that leave holes in the ice cubes.  It makes a batch of ice cubes in 7-15 minutes, much faster than making them in ice trays.  Presumably this speed is why airlines use this type of system.

Answer (score 33):

In the retail drinks trade (pubs, bars etc), machines that make these hollow ice cubes are often* used where there is not much room to store large quantities of ready-produced ice (such as in a much larger machine). The larger surface area to volume ratio means fresh ice cubes can be made more efficiently and quickly to meet demand - by the time one batch is used, the next is ready. The ice machine only needs a small storage capacity at a time to keep up.

*Of course, in warmer climates where ice is used in larger quantities, or in establishments where drinks depend on more ice (cocktail bar versus English pub), they will usually have larger capacity machines, but even then the hollow cube is common.

Answer (score 4):

Typically those are used to identify ice cubes made from drinkable water. Restaurants use them in most parts of the world and those are not limited to planes. Actually, we were at a steakhouse just yesterday and my smallest daughter asked exactly the same question. She probably was bored too.

The comments to your question are interesting because they outline several advantages of these. Risk of choking being reduced is a great one. Obviously cost saving and efficiency are important too.

Comment: *"from pure water"*? What else would ice cubes be made from?

Comment: It could be not drinkable water — or less enjoyable (i guess that's what he meant)

Comment: Yes, sorry, the term is not universal. In many parts of the world, where tap water is not drinkable, they call the one that is *pure water* or the equivalent expression in the local language.

Comment: Oh, so you might have one kind of ice cubes that you put in a bucket to keep (unopened) drinks cool, and another kind of ice cubes that are made from drinkable water that you can put in drinks. Makes sense, thanks.

Comment: Cost savings to who?

Comment: @nsn - Now, I didn't know that part before but apparently it costs less to transport cubes with holes since they are lighter and it uses less energy because there is a greater surface area to freeze.

Comment: @Itai maybe for air travel, but for the general food and beverage industry they are probably more expensive. It's definitely better to use solid cubes. Water is cheaper than any average drink. I never witnessed this case, but I worked with this industry and I can assure these things are measured to the cent.

Comment: @nsn The cost of water does not really apply in this case. IN places like fast food restaurants, you buy a cup of drink of a fixed size. If the seller can fill it with ice and less soda, they will do that to maximise profit. On an airline, most drinks are served in single-serving containers (eg cans of soda, bottles of spirits), so they would make no difference. Fruit juices and water might be served from larger cartons, so it could possibly apply there, but I think it is unlikely for reasons stated in other comments from me,.

Comment: @GregHewgill: From tap water of course. Some tap water tastes like pure water. Just the other day I was served some very yucky water that would've tasted just as bad if it had been made into ice.

Comment: I've never heard of one type of cube or another being used to identify the water source used to make the ice. That's interesting if true, but it's not the main reason cubes with holes are used. Those are used just because they can be made faster (and with less energy.)

Comment: "She probably was bored too." I guess she was just curious. I asked my father the same question when they had hollow ice cubes in the italian restaurant we went every year on wedding aniversary. I was never bored there, they had a play room for us kids!

Answer (score 2):

The surface area is bigger when it is hollow. More the surface area means that it helps cool the drink faster.